# Java Mail API in Servlet with database and error is NullPointerException

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I am sending an email to the registered student from my database and taking the users email address. and checking the email from my database, I am sending the user an email using smtp server about his prn (which is the id) and password. I have 1 servlet and a model class and 1 jsp. I have attached the screen shots of code. Thanks please its a very minor problem .do help. I am a student. thanks in advance. :) I get only 1 error which is NullPointerException

```
package com.student.connection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.activation.*;

public class Mailer {

private Connection conn = null;
private PreparedStatement ps = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;

public void send(String emailaddress) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    int prn = 0;
    final String username = "12030142084@sicsr.ac.in";
    final String password = "mypassword";
    String email = new String();
    String pass = new String();

    System.out.println("Test");
    String query = "select prn,email,password from studentdetails where email=" + emailaddress;

    conn = DBConnection.createDBConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        prn = rs.getInt(1);
        email = rs.getString("email");
        pass = rs.getString("password");
    }

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("12030142084@sicsr.ac.in"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(email));
        message.setSubject("Password Recover");
        message.setText("Your Prn is " + prn + "You Password is " + pass);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Email Sent Succsessfully");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

}

---

```
package com.student.controller;

public class ContactServlet extends HttpServlet {

private Mailer mailer;

@Override
public void init() {
    String hostname = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int port = 587;
    String username = "12030142084@sicsr.ac.in";
    String password = "mypassword";

}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        String emailaddress = request.getParameter("emailadd");
        // Do some validations and then send mail:

        String msg = "";
        try {
            msg = "Mail Successfully Sent!!";
            System.out.println("Check");

            mailer.send("emailaddress"); // here is the error
            System.out.println("Check2");

            request.setAttribute("message", "Mail succesfully sent!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/recoverpassword.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?error=" + msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.sendRedirect("recoverpassword.jsp" + msg);
            throw new ServletException("Mailer failed", e);
        }
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet ContactServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet ContactServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
```

}

---

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[ContactServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ContactServlet threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.student.controller.ContactServlet.processRequest(ContactServlet.java:50)
at com.student.controller.ContactServlet.doPost(ContactServlet.java:102)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
```

---

Jsp file is correct it only takes one user input and the id is emailadd

Some one please help.

Comment: Where do you initialize your `mailer`?

Comment: in the init method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because `mailer` has not been initialized yet.

```
private Mailer mailer; // you're just declaring mailer
...
mailer.send("emailaddress"); // without initialization you're trying to call a method on it.
```

In your `init()` method, you need to do something like this:-

```
mailer = new Mailer(); // just an example. But you need to initialize your mailer.
```

Comment: Thanks. I have initialized it now.. But i get some new error:

Comment: WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[ContactServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ContactServlet threw exception
org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'EMAILADDRESS' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMAILADDRESS' is not a column in the target table.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)

Comment: Seems to be some problem with your query. This doesn't come under the scope of this question unfortunately. Please close this question and post that problem as a separate question.

Comment: String query = "select prn,email,password from studentdetails where email=" + emailaddress; <this is my query>

Comment: Just check it once.. if you can suggest that would be really helpful. and i will close it immediately

Comment: Shouldn't your `emailaddress` be surrounded by single quotes, since its  a String. Try to change that.

Comment: Thanks.. It is definetly in the query. I will figure it out.. 
Just FYI this is the error:
SqlException: Comparisons between 'LONG VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')

Comment: Seems that you're trying to compare some `long` (or numeric value) with a string (or varchar) in the query. That's why the error.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I want to close this post now. You have been very helpful. How do i close. sorry i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You've already accepted the answer. Your question is now closed. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        mailer.send("emailaddress"); // here is the error
```

will cause NullPointerException because no where in your servlet code you are intializing the `mailer`. The mailer object is intialized to null and calling any method on it will cause NPE. Make sure you intialize it first before calling the send or any other method on it.

Comment: I have initialized it Sir.. But now i get this errro:

Comment: WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[ContactServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ContactServlet threw exception
org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'EMAILADDRESS' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMAILADDRESS' is not a column in the target table.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)